# Web Essentials: How to turn on line numbers in compiled CSS (from LESS)

Tags: asp.net, web-essentials

Some time back I'm pretty sure there were line numbers in the CSS that was compiled from LESS. I have Visual Studio 2013 U2 and WEV2.2 but no line numbers and I cannot see how to turn them on.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: `TOOLS / Options...`

Find: `Text Editor / CSS / General` - check the **Line Numbers** checkbox

Or - Use the *`Quick Launch`* *(usually the right top corner)* and type in these words:

> Text Editor CSS General

select suggested menu item and you are there to select the **Line Numbers** checkbox

Comment: Thx Radim and also my apologies as I was not specific enough.
The line-numbers is checked and they do show when I open the CSS file.
I should have explained that the line-numbers that I was talking about related to the RHS pane of the LESS panel. This definitely had line-numbers in the past and is controlled by Web Essentials AFAIK.